# Add an external user in a group

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

Using `System.DirectoryServices.Protocols` (S.DS.P), I need to add *UserX* from directory A to *GroupY* in directory B.

My `ModifyRequest` contains DistinguishedName of *GroupY* and *UserX*.

Send request throw a `DirectoryOperationException` with result code `NoSuchObject`.

I see, however, that the same operation is workable using the ActiveDirectory console (MMC snap-in). A **ForeignSecurityPrincipal** object is created in directory B and referenced as member of *GroupY*.

Comment: See if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8086322/userprincipal-findbyidentity-insists-there-is-no-such-object-on-the-server) helps

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use the syntax `<SID=...>` (replace ... by UserX objectSid) as the attribute value in the `ModifyRequest` object.